# Do JWs believe the water canopy theory and do they think it will be restored?

Tags: creation, eschatology, jehovahs-witnesses, flood-of-noah

Many creationist have beliefs concerning the pre-flood environment on earth.
Are Jehovah Witnesses adamant about the water canopy being the source of flood waters? Do JWs believe the restored earth will have a restored canopy?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  We are glad you are here.  We you have a minute, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what we are about.  *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, which is fine, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The water canopy concept can take on various forms. Typically though, it is viewed as an atmospheric feature that existed right before the flood, but is no longer intact. Proponents will assert that this concept has foundation in scripture. However, as the [The Zondervan Pictorial Bible Dictionary, 1963 (1969 printing)](https://archive.org/details/zondervanpictori0000tenn/page/284/mode/2up) states: "The canopy idea, although firmly entrenched in literature, has doubtful Biblical authority."

Genesis 1:7 is commonly referenced as the basis for a canopy theory. Rather than using the word "canopy," the Jehovah's Witnesses' Bible ([New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures (Study Edition)](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/1/1#study=discover)), states: "Then God went on to make the expanse and divided the waters beneath the expanse from the waters above the expanse. And it was so."

Their Bible translation has a cross-reference to Proverbs 8:27,28: "When he prepared the heavens, I was there; When he marked out the horizon on the surface of the waters, When he established the clouds above, When he founded the fountains of the deep,"

At Psalms 148:4, the [New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures—With References](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/Rbi8/19/148#study=discover) states: "Praise him, YOU heavens of the heavens, And YOU waters that are above the heavens."

Explaining the verse further, the [Watchtower (w87 3/15 pp. 25)](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1987206#h=39) states:

> What are the ‘waters above the heavens’? The psalmist apparently meant the water-carrying clouds above the earth that empty themselves from time to time in the form of rain, which eventually flows back into the oceans. This cycle is essential to life, and its very existence gives praise to the Creator. Since the atmospheric expanse between the earth and the clouds can be spoken of as heavens, the psalmist referred to the clouds as the ‘waters above the heavens.’

This verse has a cross-reference to Genesis 1:7. Thus, at times Jehovah's Witnesses have understood scriptural language referring to "the waters above" to simply mean clouds.

Although they cannot rely solely on Biblical descriptions to support a canopy concept, this has not prevented Jehovah's Witnesses from espousing the idea. This is seen clearly when examining the language used by the [Aid](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200011122?q=canopy&p=par) book (1971) under the Deluge entry. In time though, the language used in this entry was updated with the release of the [Insight](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001150) book (1988). Throughout the entire entry, the word canopy was removed and any such references were replaced with the original scriptural terminologies. More recently, when comparing these older publications to newer ones, it is clear that Jehovah's Witnesses are no longer adamant about the water canopy theory being the source of flood waters.

When explaining the source of flood waters, they now quote what the Bible directly says about the event. For example, the [January 1, 2004 Watchtower](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2004004#h=18) makes no mention of the word "canopy." It merely cites the applicable Bible verses pertaining to the referenced accounts, using the translated wording of the actual scriptures.

It should be noted that the [*Awake!* March 2014](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102014083?q=canopy&p=par) does not affirm the belief that a water vapor canopy existed immediately before the flood of Noah's day. The Awake! article describes a canopy as existing during the second creative day. Later, the article mentions the fourth day stating: "The sun and moon become discernible from the earth’s surface." The atmosphere continued to change from the 2nd to the 3rd day and then even more-so during the 4th day. Thus, this reference to a canopy may simply describe the state of an unfinished Earth during the early creative process.

The 1991 public talk outline for Sunday sermons entitled: **"THE FLOOD OF NOAH’S DAY HAS MEANING FOR US"** had made various references to the canopy. It stated in part: "Vast quantity of water vapor could have served as an insulating moisture blanket" This public talk outline was later revised in 2015 with a revised title: **"THE FLOOD OF NOAH’S DAY AND YOU."** In this version, there are no references made to any sort of canopy. There are no references to other source materials that describe a canopy. The outline does not even address the source of the flood waters.

Since there are no recent publications promoting a pre-flood canopy or its utilization as a source for flood waters, this teaching must be outdated. At the same time, Jehovah's Witnesses have never published any sort of retraction or clarification on the matter. As a result, while the organization does not actively teach it, individual Jehovah's Witnesses might still promote it in conversation. Some individuals might speculate about its future "restoration," but this is not based on official teachings of the organization.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 5):

The belief of Jehovah's Witnesses and other religions regarding a water canopy that existed at the time of earth's creation is not a concept that is a result of doctrine but one that is advanced in the Bible itself. [Genesis 1:7](http://www.biblestudytools.com/genesis/1-7.html) says: "So God made the expanse and separated the water under the expanse from the water above it. And it was so." The [Jewish Tanach](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/jps/gen001.htm) agrees with this same concept saying, "And God said: 'Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters.' And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament; and it was so."

Jehovah's Witnesses recently published a series of articles on creation which affirms the belief in a canopy of vapor that existed in the pre-flood era (see [*Awake!* March 2014)](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102014083?q=canopy&p=par). Additionally an article from the [January 1, 2004 *Watchtower*](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2004004#h=18:0-18:457) magazine says this: *"Where did the water causing the global Flood come from? During the second creative period, or “day,” when the earth’s atmospheric “expanse” was formed, there were waters “beneath the expanse” and waters “above the expanse.” (Genesis 1:6, 7) The waters “beneath” were those already on earth. The waters “above” were huge quantities of moisture suspended high above the earth, forming a “vast watery deep.” These waters fell upon the earth in Noah’s day."*

In regards to whether that canopy will ever exist again has not been officially discussed in recent Jehovah's Witnesses literature.